# Read redshift in parallel using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to query Amazon Redshift using PySpark? I've tried to find this on stackoverflow but there are only old questions which their solution does not work for me.

I am trying using the [Redshift Data Source for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) but it is not working.

My code is like the same as the data source docs (of course I am replacing the required fields):

```
sc = # existing SparkContext
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql_context.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshifthost:5439/database?user=username&password=pass") \
    .option("dbtable", "my_table") \
    .option("tempdir", "s3n://path/for/temp/data") \
    .load()

df.show()
```

I am trying to run this using PyCharm with PySpark version 3.0.0, however I get the error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.redshift. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:674)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:648)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:648)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:648)
    ... 14 more
```

This error is might due to the fact that I may not be importing correctly the JAR file for Redshift JDBC (as you can see I am running in PyCharm), I also does not know how to import it using pycharm.

I am also trying to run it by command prompt with the following command:
`spark-submit --jars RedshiftJDBC41-1.2.12.1017.jar --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:2.0.0 query.py`

But I get the following error after the execution:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o50.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
        at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Parameters$MergedParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:78)
        at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:72)
        at com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 20 more
```

Is there some way to run this query in parallel using pyspark? I've saw that the redshift connector has been discontinued from the developers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark 3.0 is built with scala 2.12. The redshift package you are attempting to use is built for scala 2.10. It does not appear that the redshift package has a 2.12 release.

Spark 2.x was built with scala 2.11. If this is an option, there is a 2.11 release of the spark-redshift package [available](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-redshift).